# exec.Command does not register error from Go's own pprof tool

Tags: go, pprof

Here is my code:

```
cmd := exec.Command("go", "tool", "pprof", "-dot", "-lines", "http://google.com")
out, err := cmd.Output()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
println(string(out))
```

When I run the exact same command in my console, I see:

```
$ go tool pprof -dot -lines http://google.com 
Fetching profile from http://google.com/profilez
Please wait... (30s)
server response: 404 Not Found
```

However, my go program does not register that this is an error. Oddly, the variable out prints as an empty string and err is nil. What is going on?

To clarify, I am profiling http://google.com to purposefully create an error. I would normally profile a real Go application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text

```
Fetching profile from http://google.com/profilez
Please wait... (30s)
server response: 404 Not Found
```

is written to stderr.  Your program captures stdout, which is empty. Consider calling:

```
out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
```

to grab both stdout and stderr.

`cmd.Output()` and `cmd.CombinedOutput()` return `err == nil` because the command exits with status zero. Perhaps an issue should be filed requesting that the command exit with non-zero status.